# What is meant by phrase "bid to broker"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across this sentence" Moussa resumes bid to broker compromise in Beirut" but couldn't understand it.

Comment: Try looking up *bid* as noun and *broker* as verb.

Comment: Seeing how it's a news headline that is accompanied by *an entire article specifically dedicated to explaining what it means*, I suggest you start by simply reading said article.

Answer (score 1):

To translate out of headlinese:

> Moussa resumes his bid to broker a compromise in Beirut.

That is, "bid to broker" means "efforts to mediate."

A key to understanding this phrase is to realize that "broker" is a verb: it does not refer to a person who conducts business transactions on behalfof another person.

Comment: Thanks guys but if you can articulate this phrase in a different sentence that would be much helpful.

Comment: @TechNoCraZy it isn't a common phrase like "mark to market", it is just an ad hoc phrase like "desire to eat" or "disinclination to gossip."

Comment: @TechNoCraZy- And it really doesn't even go together like that ("bid to broker") it's more like "resumes his bid"  "to broker a compromise"

Answer (score 0):

"Moussa resumes bid to broker compromise in Beirut" can also be said as:

> Moussa resumes his efforts to come to a compromise in Beirut.

Where we use bid as a noun and broker as a verb to mean:

> **Bid**: an attempt or effort to achieve something.
>
> **Broker**: arrange or negotiate (an agreement).

You've likely heard these used separately in other expressions, such as:

> In 1923, Hitler made a bid for power in Munich.
>
> The fighting in Munich continued despite the government's attempts to broker a ceasefire.